# How train a connectionist model to recognise objects

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, supervised-learning

I want to train a connectionist model to recognize objects in photos, which types of invariance would I have to deal with, and how could I try to solve these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The learning and recognition system uses confidence values for the presence of a feature. The network can recognize multiple objects simultaneously when the corresponding overlapped feature train is presented at the input. An error function is defined, and it is minimized for obtaining the optimal set of object classes. The model is capable of learning each individual object in the supervised mode. The theory of learning is developed based on some probabilistic measures.

More details in [A Connectionist Model for Category Perception: Theory and Implementation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jayanta_Basak2/publication/3301718_A_Connectionist_Model_for_Category_Perception_Theory_and_Implementation/links/55377c8a0cf268fd0018a106/A-Connectionist-Model-for-Category-Perception-Theory-and-Implementation.pdf)

I hope this can help you.